# Is there a way to use non Tuple objects with splat operator in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang, splat

Is there some function or syntax construction to make next examples work?

Invoke `Hash#values_at` function with an `Array` argument:

```
h = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
ary = ["a", "b"]
h.values_at(*ary) # Error: argument to splat must be a tuple, not Array(String)
```

Pass `Hash` to initialize class or struct:

```
struct Point                                                                                                 
    def initialize(@x : Int32, @y : Int32)                                                                     
    end                                                                                                        
end
h = {"x" => 1, "y" => 2}
Point.new(**h) # Error: argument to double splat must be a named tuple, not Hash(String, Int32)
```

Comment: I believe the short answer is no. But I've found that, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you can get what you want out of Crystal in other ways. Can you give broader context to your question? Why are you trying to do these things?

Comment: 1 Indexing Arrays with Array could be very handy when working with datasets (like in R or Numpy). 2 do not want to duplicate initialization for hash (invoke initialize with typing all keys).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example might be impossible, depending on the circumstances. However if the length of elements is fixed, you can do:

```
h = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
ary = ["a", "b"]
p h.values_at(*{String, String}.from(ary))
```

https://carc.in/#/r/3oot See [Tuple.from](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/Tuple.html#from%28array%3AArray%29%3Aself-class-method)

`NamedTuple` supports the same approach:

```
struct Point                                                                                                 
    def initialize(@x : Int32, @y : Int32)                                                                     
    end                                                                                                        
end
h = {"x" => 1, "y" => 2}

p Point.new(**{x: Int32, y: Int32}.from(h))
```

https://carc.in/#/r/3oov See [NamedTuple.from](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/NamedTuple.html#from%28hash%3AHash%29%3Aself-class-method)

Both of these are just some sugar around ensuring types and decomposing the structure manually at runtime and mainly useful when your data comes from an external source, such as being parsed from JSON.

Of course it's preferred to create and use `Tuple` over `Array` and `NamedTuple` over `Hash` in the first place where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Array and Hash are dynamically expanding containers, the number of elements can change at runtime and maybe the array might be empty when you try to splat it.

Tuple and NamedTuple consist of a fixed number of elements which is known at compile time so they can be used for splats. If the format of your data containers does not change, you can just use Tuple and NamedTuple instead.

```
ary = {"a", "b"}
h.values_at(*ary)
```

Comment: What is the best way of indexing Array or Hash with Array created at runtime?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @MikhailGordeev I believe, you will need a (Named)Tuple for that anyway, it's by design. So it's better to change your code to have that (Named)Tuple at compile time instead of Array which you should have to convert if future.